# RewriteRule only works in one direction?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, plesk

This rewrite rule works.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

This rewrite rule doesn't

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

The .co.uk is an alias in Plesk 11 for the .com. It's on Apache2 (API version 20051115). It has nginx in the mix too but I don't know the exact details as it's on shared hosting.

It has been working for years but the host has altered the server config (without telling, grrr!) and broken the redirect. Firefox tells me that "The page isn't redirecting properly".

Comment: Are those both rules in same .htaccess file?

Comment: The second one is the original rule, in .htaccess in the root of the domain. It no longer works (server fails to return a page, FF returns above error). The first pair does work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your rules with these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)example\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```